# Encoder ICs replaces shift registers?

Tags: integrated-circuit, shift-register, encoder

Sorry in advance am a kid or below that in electronics. On learning about shift registers (Eg:74hc165 input shift register) and encoder, decoder ICs (HT12D, HT12E). I really got a similarity between HT12E and 74HC165 input shift register. According to their explanation 74HC165 can convert 8 parallel input into serial output.

HT12E can convert 12bit (including address bits) to serial output. So really getting confused what is the difference between encoders and so called shift registers. Both sounds same for a beginner. Anyone please explain the difference.

Comment: Who is "they" in "their explanation"? and, have you actually like tried to google the datasheet of the HT12D? Where is the same functionality as a shift register in the block diagram? This question lacks the minimum amount of research. You're comparing apples to oranges. Or more, apples to stock options or something.

Answer (score 4):

The HT12E is a lot more than *just* a shift register. It 'encodes' the bits into a series of pulses which are designed to be transmitted over a wireless link (Infrared or RF) and 'decoded' by the HT12D.

The link may not support DC signal levels and is inherently noisy, so the HT12E converts the bits into [Manchester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code) code which has no DC bias, repeats each bit sequence at least four times so the receiver can reject errors, and prepends pilot and sync pulses so the receiver can lock onto the start of each transmission.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

74HC165 = 8 bit PISO parallel in serial out with load ,  clock, inhibit and serial inputs with output occurring only once unless output is fed back to serial input.

HT12E = 8 bit address 4 bit data PISO with clock enable to transmit and repeat while TE is low. so it has clock, counters and SR's. You add resonator for choice of clock.

Big difference. 8 vs 12 and clock, counters included

Address and data can be all address if you choose but intended for 8 with 4 bit data or 12 bit targets for toggle (1bit) purpose or other combinations of 12 bits.